# UIAlertView Coming after data upload not before start

Tags: iphone, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am showing activity view but it showing after data to server is uploaded only  may be due to main thread stop is there any way to show this activity while data is uploading. both at same time.

```
  -(IBAction)startSyncButtonAction{


UIAlertView* alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

indicator.center = CGPointMake(150, 100);
[indicator startAnimating];
[alert addSubview:indicator];

CereniaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CereniaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

for (int i=0; i<[appDelegate.coffeeArray count]; i++) {

Coffee *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:i];


    int mycount=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];
    NSLog(@"My Array count is %d",mycount);


NSString*device_Id=coffeeObj.device_Id;
NSString*R1=coffeeObj.R1;
NSString*R2=coffeeObj.R2;
NSString*R3=coffeeObj.R3;
NSString*R4=coffeeObj.R4;
NSString*R5=coffeeObj.R5;
NSString*R6=coffeeObj.R6;
NSString*R7=coffeeObj.R7;
NSString*R8=coffeeObj.R8;
NSString*R9=coffeeObj.R9;
NSString*R10=coffeeObj.R10;
NSString*R11=coffeeObj.R11;
NSString*R12=coffeeObj.R12;
NSString*R13=coffeeObj.R13;
NSString*R14=coffeeObj.R14;     


NSString*update_date_time=coffeeObj.update_date_time;

    NSString*teritory1=coffeeObj.teritory;



    int mycount1=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];


    NSLog(@"My Array After delete is %d",mycount1);


    NSLog(@"device_Id%@",device_Id);
    NSLog(@"R1%@",R1);
    NSLog(@"R2%@",R2);
    NSLog(@"R3%@",R3);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R4);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R5);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R6);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R7);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R8);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R9);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R10);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R11);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R12);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R13);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R14);

    NSLog(@"update_date_time%@",update_date_time);

    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"device_Id=%@&R1=%@&R2=%@&R3=%@&R4=%@&R5=%@&R6=%@&R7=%@&R8=%@&R9=%@&R10=%@&R11=%@&R12=%@&R13=%@&R14=%@&update_date_time=%@&teritory1=%@",device_Id,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R10,R11,R12,R13,R14,update_date_time,teritory1];



    NSLog(post);
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/pfizersurvey/SyncSurveySTD.php"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];



    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",data);

      }


for (int i=0; i<[appDelegate.coffeeArray count]; i++) {

    Coffee *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:i];


     [appDelegate removeCoffee:coffeeObj];

}




[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    }
```

Comment: do u have problem with alert or activity?

Comment: they both are same actity is shown on alert view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put on the main thread the alert and the uploading code, so when opening the alert call to an upload method (let say (void)uploadData) on another thread. Your code just stuck the UI until the all data is done uploading then the UI is free for the alert.

In the action  -(IBAction)startSyncButtonAction, call to the alert and the UI stuff:

```
UIAlertView* alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

indicator.center = CGPointMake(150, 100);
[indicator startAnimating];
[alert addSubview:indicator];

CereniaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CereniaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

for (int i=0; i<[appDelegate.coffeeArray count]; i++) {

Coffee *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:i];


    int mycount=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];
    NSLog(@"My Array count is %d",mycount);


NSString*device_Id=coffeeObj.device_Id;
NSString*R1=coffeeObj.R1;
NSString*R2=coffeeObj.R2;
NSString*R3=coffeeObj.R3;
NSString*R4=coffeeObj.R4;
NSString*R5=coffeeObj.R5;
NSString*R6=coffeeObj.R6;
NSString*R7=coffeeObj.R7;
NSString*R8=coffeeObj.R8;
NSString*R9=coffeeObj.R9;
NSString*R10=coffeeObj.R10;
NSString*R11=coffeeObj.R11;
NSString*R12=coffeeObj.R12;
NSString*R13=coffeeObj.R13;
NSString*R14=coffeeObj.R14;     


NSString*update_date_time=coffeeObj.update_date_time;

    NSString*teritory1=coffeeObj.teritory;



    int mycount1=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];


    NSLog(@"My Array After delete is %d",mycount1);


    NSLog(@"device_Id%@",device_Id);
    NSLog(@"R1%@",R1);
    NSLog(@"R2%@",R2);
    NSLog(@"R3%@",R3);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R4);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R5);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R6);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R7);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R8);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R9);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R10);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R11);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R12);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R13);
    NSLog(@"R4%@",R14);

    NSLog(@"update_date_time%@",update_date_time);
```

at the end of that call to a method in another thread

```
// Perform all the data initializations on a new thread
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(uploadData:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Then you need another method

```
   -(void) uploadData:(id) obj 
{
 NSLog(post);
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/pfizersurvey/SyncSurveySTD.php"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];



    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",data);

      }


for (int i=0; i<[appDelegate.coffeeArray count]; i++) {

    Coffee *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:i];


     [appDelegate removeCoffee:coffeeObj];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataDoneLoading:) withObject:_photos waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

and put there all the upload code. at the end "dataDoneLoading" to stuff on mainthread again

Comment: how to do this can you help me explain this

Comment: keep the flow of your app.

Comment: how will i add flow of app they are on othe button clicks this not making perfect thing

Comment: [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataDoneLoading:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; just going back to the main thread I think that you can put an nnslog in the dataDoneLoading to see that it's OK

Comment: NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x61796c0 of class __NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
showing like this

Comment: how to stop this thread  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(uploadData:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

Comment: NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x61796c0 of class __NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place it is a new different question. there is a lot of answers in here regarding this try to see if it came from the nsurlconnection or before

Answer (score 0):

Use

[self performSelector:@selector(displayAlertView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

Method.